# How to check if 2 class objects have same parameters inside a list in python?

Tags: python, class

I have an AI algorithm program in which I'm adding Nodes (the object class) into a list for processing. My Class is built as follows-

```
    def __init__(self, data, parent):
        self.data = data
        self.parent = parent
        self.parentweight = 0
```

No 2 objects can have all the exact same parameters in my use case, since that should mean that both are the same one object. In case I generate a Node which has all the values same as some other random Node in the list, it should not be appended to the list and the program should move on. How can I do that?

The code that appends to the list in question-

```
visited = [] #Initiated globally

if (miss_x !=2): 
            temp_right = Node(self.move_right(miss_y, miss_x), self)
            
            if temp_right not in visited:
                visited.append(temp_right)
                final.append(temp_right)
```

Here's the pseudocode for what I want to do-

```
if (miss_x !=2): 
            temp_right = Node(self.move_right(miss_y, miss_x), self)

            if (temp_right.data and temp_right.parent) not in visited for any node:
                visited.append(temp_right)
                final.append(temp_right)
```

I thought of doing this in another method like so-

```
def not_in(self, visited):
        for node in visited:
            if (self.data == node.data) and (self.parent==node.parent):
                return 0
        return 1
```

But I feel like there's a better way to do this, since it seems wasteful to check the complete list for every time another node is added.

Another piece of information I found was using _eq_ as follows-

```
def __eq__(self, other) : 
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

But I'm not sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to efficiently check for prior existence upon creation of a new instance of `Node` is to use a Python `set` where each element is a `tuple` of parameters uniquely identifying a `Node`. For example:

```py
existingNodes = set()
def makeNode(nodeSet, data, parent):
    node = Node(data, parent)
    tup = (node.data, node.parent)
    if tup in nodeSet:
        return None
    nodeSet.add(tup)
    return node

root = makeNode(existingNodes, 0, None)
node = makeNode(existingNodes, 1, root)
node2 = makeNode(existingNodes, 1, root)
[print(f"{'None' if n is None else n.data}") for n in (root, node, node2)]
```

Output:

```
0
1
None
```

In the example above, `root` is created and returned by `makeNode()` as is `node`, but in the attempted creation of `node2`, the parameters are detected as duplicates (same as for `node`) and `makeDef()` returns None to signal this.

**UPDATE:**
To handle data in the form of a 2D list, as OP has suggested may be required, the following approach can be used to convert the data to a hashable nested tuple, assuming the 2D list does not change for the lifetime of the Node:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, parent):
        self.data = data
        self.parent = parent
        self.parentweight = 0    

existingNodes = set()
def makeNode(nodeSet, nodeData, parent):
    node = Node(nodeData, parent)
    dataTup = tuple(tuple(x) for x in nodeData.data)
    tup = (dataTup, node.parent)
    if tup in nodeSet:
        return None
    nodeSet.add(tup)
    return node

class NodeData:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

root = makeNode(existingNodes, NodeData([[1,2],[3,4]]), None)
node = makeNode(existingNodes, NodeData([[5,6],[7,8]]), root)
node2 = makeNode(existingNodes, NodeData([[5,6],[7,8]]), root)
[print(f"{'None' if n is None else n.data.data}") for n in (root, node, node2)]
```

Output is:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[5, 6], [7, 8]]
None
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this earlier, but my Data is actually a 2d list, and using

if tup in nodeSet:

raises TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

What can I do then?

Comment: Yes, `list` is not hashable in Python, but `tuple` is. Assuming the 2d `list` does not change for the lifetime of the `Node`, you can use a 2d `tuple` instead. Either start out by using `tuple`s for your data, or convert the data to a `tuple` at the  time of adding to and searching within the `set`. Alternatively, you can wrap your 2d data in an object (by defining your own `NodeData` class which you then assign to the `data` attribute in the `Node` class) and put that object into tup

Comment: @Birinder Singh I have updated my answer to show an example of how to work with data in the form of a 2D list.